# R cluster.vcov function not found

Tags: r

I am trying to use the cluster.vcov in R but it keeps telling me

`cluster.vcov(regression1, data$country`

`Error in cluster.vcov(regression1, data$country) :  could not find function "cluster.vcov`

I have tried installing the package "multiwayvcov" but it says that such package does not exist. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiwayvcov` package has been deprecated as mentioned [here](https://sites.google.com/site/npgraham1/research/code). The author recommends to use the `sandwich` package now which has the same functionality.

However, I can install both `multiwayvcov` and `sandwich` package on my system with `R version 4.0.3` using `install.packages('multiwayvcov')` and `install.packages("sandwich")`.